# MySqlConnection.StateChange is never Fetching

Tags: c#, mysql

How MySqlConnection.StateChange does work?

I have following code.

```
conn.StateChange += ConnectionStateChanged;

private void ConnectionStateChanged(Object sender, StateChangeEventArgs e) {
    switch (e.CurrentState) {
    // is never equal to Fetching
    }
}

public DataTable Query(string query) {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (MySqlDataAdapter a = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn)) {
        try {
            a.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 5;
            a.Fill(dt);
        } catch {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Why ConnectionStateChanged is never called with ConnectionState.Fetching nor ConnectionState.Executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I may misunderstand [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but these states don't seem to be implemented (the enum values are just "reserved", even in .net 4.5) :

> **Executing** The connection object is executing a command. (This value is
>   reserved for future versions of the product.)

and

> **Fetching**  The connection object is retrieving data. (This value is
>   reserved for future versions of the product.)

Comment: Oh snap. So is there any other official way to get state of the connection?

Comment: @PeterGoldwynn as far as I know (but don't know much on this point), you can just get open, closed (and connecting in 4.5)...

Comment: Well, since open, closed and connecting are supported I will implement it in a standard manner. Unfortunately I also need to know a state of the connection during query execution.
Anyways I came up with an idea to manually fire up the StateChange event passing appropriate parameters.